# How do i executes a REPLACE statement in batch

Tags: php, codeigniter

In codeogniter 3 there are many batch operation for insert and update.

Example :

```
/* $this->db->insert_batch(); */
$data = array(
        array(
                'title' => 'My title',
                'name' => 'My Name',
                'date' => 'My date'
        ),
        array(
                'title' => 'Another title',
                'name' => 'Another Name',
                'date' => 'Another date'
        )
);

$this->db->insert_batch('mytable', $data);
```

=========================================================

```
/* $this->db->update_batch(); */
$data = array(
   array(
      'title' => 'My title' ,
      'name' => 'My Name 2' ,
      'date' => 'My date 2'
   ),
   array(
      'title' => 'Another title' ,
      'name' => 'Another Name 2' ,
      'date' => 'Another date 2'
   )
);

$this->db->update_batch('mytable', $data, 'title');
```

**but there is not batch meths for REPLACE can any one guide me for replace data in batch**

```
/* $this->db->replace_batch(); */

$data = array(
        array(
                'title' => 'My title',
                'name' => 'My Name',
                'date' => 'My date'
        ),
        array(
                'title' => 'Another title',
                'name' => 'Another Name',
                'date' => 'Another date'
        )
);

$this->db->replace_batch('mytable', $data, 'title');
```

thank you so much guys....

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.using `foreach` loop.

```
$data = array(
        array(
                'title' => 'My title',
                'name' => 'My Name',
                'date' => 'My date'
        ),
        array(
                'title' => 'Another title',
                'name' => 'Another Name',
                'date' => 'Another date'
        )
);
```

**Then**

```
foreach ($data as $key=>$value)
{
$this->db->replace('mytable', $value, 'title');
}
```

Comment: notworking with this, when my record are more then 500 its getting very slow or stuck in process